# mypy: Correct way of type-annotating list of multiple types

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a list of lists that each contain a file object and a list of strings:

```
sample = [
    [fileobject1, ['hello', 'world']],
    [fileobject2, ['something', 'else']]
]
```

I type annotated `sample` like this:

`List[List[Union[IO, List[str]]]]`

Further in my code I call some methods on the first (0) and second (1) entry of the inner list.

For example like this to clear the most inner list:

`entry[1].clear()`

The code runs fine, but mypy rightly complains that:

`Item "IO[Any]" of "Union[IO[Any], List[str]]" has no attribute "clear"`

How would I type-annotate this correctly? Maybe use a different data structure all together?

Comment: The way this is written, it looks like a `dict` would be both easier to use and faster, e.g. `sample = {
    fileobject1: ['hello', 'world'],
    fileobject2: ['something', 'else']
}`
But without knowing what these 'other methods' are, it's tough to say

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather then using lists, you should use tuples. For example:

```
sample: List[Tuple[IO, List[str]]] = [
   (fileobject1, ['hello', 'world']),
   (fileobject2, ['something', 'else']),
]
```

Mypy assumes that lists are homogeneous: they will only ever contain one kind of type. Tuples are meant to contain heterogeneous data: each item is allowed to have a different type.

Note that tuples aren't the only types you could use here -- you could create and use a custom class, or used NamedTuples... But switching to tuples would likely be the simplest fix here.

Comment: How about if the list comes from a third-party library that we have no control over and which does not use type hints?

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an official reference for "Mypy assumes that lists are homogeneous"?

Comment: how would `['one', ['two','three'],'four']` be annotated with this approach? where there can be a varying number of values, in different places. This question is very broad, so comes up in google - but the answer seems to deal with a very narrow scope.

Comment: @baxx -- In that case, one approach is to use basically the same approach described in the question and do something like `List[Union[str, List[str]]]`. If specifying the full union is too verbose, you could also do something like `List[object]` instead. (The code you write will be nearly the same either way, since you'll have to sprinkle in a few runtime type checks when using your list.) Alternatively, if you're ok with [introducing some dynamism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39817081/646543), `List[Any]` always works as a fallback.

Comment: If the types in your list happen to share a common base type, you can also use that instead of `object` to get a bit more precision. For example, we could do `List[Sequence[str]]` for your example, since both `str` and `List[str]` happen to be subtypes of `Sequence[str]`. Then, you can freely perform operations that are common to both `str` and `List[str]` such as iteration or indexing w/o needing extra runtime checks.

Comment: The final strategy is to restructure your code so it "normalizes" your data to become more regular and easier to type. The "use a tuple" strategy in my example is implicitly advocating for this approach, for example. Of course, normalization isn't always a good idea or convenient to do -- but _can_ help you simplify your code if you can pull it off.