# Python annotation for list of specific types

Tags: python, list, type-annotation

I would like to annotate a `list` of a `str` and an `int`, e.g.:

```
    state = ['mystring', 4]
```

I can't use tuple, becuase I have to change the integer without changing the reference of the state (it is passed to functions, which also have to modify it). *Note that this is a typical tuple case, just since `int` is immutable in python, ...*

```
def myfunc(state: ?) -> bool:
    ...
    state[1] += 1
    ...
    return success
```

What is the best way to annotate it? I tried

```
    state: list[str, int]
```

(similarly to a tuple) which compiles well, but `mypy` throws an exception, that `list` expects only a single argument. I can also use

```
    state: list[str|int]
```

But this is a "different type" for different use cases.

Comment: This looks like the job for a custom class, not reusing the much, much more general list. Note that lists don’t have static positions, since they support insertion and deletion.

Comment: Would you be fine with changing the value to `('mystring', [4])`?

Comment: Or if you really want to stick with a list, there's always `list[Any]`. You're not going to get the type checker to do what you want with a list, so you might as well use `Any` to tell it to just ignore the element types.

Comment: You could also use a [TypedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) for this (Python >= 3.8 only).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, probably creating a specific class for this case is the proper way. This is not a list, I used it as a workaround instead of tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy: Correct way of type-annotating list of multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544118/mypy-correct-way-of-type-annotating-list-of-multiple-types)

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks. No, my post contained the most information info from there.

Comment: Based on @MisterMiyagi's comment I wrote an answer.

Comment: @FERcsI That's what the answer to the question I've linked also says basically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @MisterMiyagi-s comment, the answer is, that we shouldn't use `list` as an alternative to `tuple`, just because we need to modifiy the values. List should be a sequence of objects of the same type (or more types).

The proper solution could be:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class State:
    text: str
    pos: int
    
...

state = State('mystring', 4)

...

def myfunc(state: State) -> bool:
    ...
    state.pos += 1
    ...
    return success
```