# What should the return type of __deepcopy__ be?

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking, mypy

I'm trying to implement my own `__deepcopy__` function. The following is my MCVE:

```py
from typing import Dict

class Foo:
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo: Dict[int, object]) -> Foo:
        return Foo()
```

When run, I get the error `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined` on the line with the `def`.

Note that

```py
class Bar:
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return Bar()
```

runs just fine.

What can I do in order to get the `__deepcopy__` function to both have the right type annotations and also run?

Comment: For now, I've just replaced `Foo` with `object` and it seems to be working fine, but it bothers me because the correct type should really be `Foo`.

Comment: also, you may be interested in [typing.Any vs object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817081/typing-any-vs-object)