# What type hint should I write when the return type is uncertain?

Tags: python, type-hinting

For example, if I define this function:

```py
def open_pkl(src: str) -> ?:
    with open('serialized.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data
```

what type hint should I write for the return value?

Now, I write the function as:

```py
def open_pkl(src: str):
    with open('serialized.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data
```

Is there type a hint for an uncertain return type?

Comment: [`typing.Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any)

Comment: @DanielWalker, yes. both answers are helpful for me.

Comment: @DanielWalker Ok, I have done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options: `object` and `typing.Any`.  Returning an `object` signals to the caller of the function that nothing can be assumed about the returned object (since everything is an `object`, saying that something is an `object` gives no information).  So, if a user were to do

```py
def open_pkl(src: str) -> object:
    ...

something = open_pkl('some/file')
print(len(something))
```

that would be a type violation, even if the object were a `list`, because `object`s per se don't have a `__len__` method.

`typing.Any`, on the other hand, is like a wild card which could hypothetically be anything.  So, if you reworked the above example to have a `typing.Any` return type, there would be no type violation.  Does a `typing.Any` have a `__len__` method?  Maybe.  Who says it couldn't?

To summarize, you should use `object` if you want to "force" (because type hints are just suggestions) your users to verify the type of any object returned by this function.  Use `typing.Any` to be more lax.

Comment: Great points. For more on this, there's [typing.Any vs object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39817081/11082165)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`typing.Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) to indicate an unconstrained type.

```
from typing import Any

def open_pkl(src: str) -> Any:
    with open('serialized.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data
```

Do note that using `Any` as a type hint essentially turns off type checking. Per the docs:

> - Every type is compatible with `Any`.
> - `Any` is compatible with every type.

Hence, any usages of `Any` will pass type checking.

Comment: in this case, I'd strongly encourage `object` and validation