# TypeVar in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, type-variables

I ran the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
%load_ext nb_mypy
from typing import Any, List, Union, TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T",int,str)

def first(container: List[T]) -> T:
    return container[2]

ls: List[Any] = [1,"hello",("hello",)]
first(ls)
```

And the result was:

```
('hello',)
```

Here, I constrained the variable `T` to represent only `str` or `int` types. Then, I constrained the `container` parameter of the function. I believed that the elements in container could only be int or str, but when I tried to pass a list `ls` containing tuples, mypy did not report an error. I cannot understand why.

Doesn't `List[T]` mean that container can only contain variables of type `T`? Here, I also constrained the return value of the function to be of type `T`, but it seems to have had no effect, as the function still returned a tuple, and mypy did not report any errors.

Comment: There is no typing contrait in Python. Even if you declare something as some type, you can assign later whatever you want. Same for function/method parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've annotated `ls` as `List[Any]`. `Any` is Mypy's escape hatch, that tells it not to type check, and to accept any operation on the object. For instance,

```py
x: Any = 3
x + "foo"
```

type checks just fine. If you remove the `List[Any]` hint, or change it `list[object]` or `list[int | str | tuple[str]]` (Python 3.10+ syntax), you get an error as you'd expect.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817081/typing-any-vs-object) may be of help.